# How can you avoid clobbering configuration files when installing with make

Tags: make

When using the autotools build system and installing with `make install` how is it possible to avoid clobbering existing configuration files?

I've defined a configuration file in a `Makefile.am` like so:

```
dist_sysconf_DATA = $(top_srcdir)/server.conf
```

How is it possible to define data files in such a way that `make install` will not clobber an existing version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your install target not copy the file if it's already there, or copy it under a different name. Here's an example from [man-db](http://man-db.nongnu.org/).

```
# We deliberately leave the configuration file in place on uninstall, since
# it may contain local customisations.
distuninstallcheck_listfiles = \
        find . -type f -print | grep -v 'etc/man_db\.conf'

noinst_DATA = man_db.conf

install-data-hook:
        @if test -f $(DESTDIR)$(config_file); then \
                echo "$(DESTDIR)$(config_file) already exists; overwrite manuall
        else \
                test -z "$(config_file_dirname)" || $(MKDIR_P) "$(DESTDIR)$(conf
                echo " $(INSTALL_DATA) man_db.conf $(DESTDIR)$(config_file)"; \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) man_db.conf $(DESTDIR)$(config_file); \
        fi
```

But the best thing to do would be to keep a strict separation between installed files and user customization, so that users never have to change a distributed file. Make your application read its configuration from both `/etc/myapp.conf` and `/usr/share/myapp/default.conf`, so that an empty file under `/etc` results in the default behavior and settings under `/etc` override those under `/usr`.